# Collaborating and protecting intellectual property with Matlab

Tags: matlab, collaboration

Dear stack overflow community,

For a project I am collaborating with a large research institute. They have created a certain solver for my problem, written in Matlab. However, they are not willing to share the source code (m-file) of this solver because of intellectual property (IP) reasons.

I am fine with not getting the source code of the solver, since I do not need to modify it for my work. However, I do need to call the solver in a Matlab environment. Is there any way for the research institute to share their code with me, without giving me acces a readable m-file? Maybe the Matlab compiler can be used?

The solver is coded in an OOP manner. In other programming environments, I would try to create some sort of API. Your thoughts on a solution are most welcome.

Comment: A company or institute relying on keeping secrets from the customer is highly questionable. Does their "intellectual property" really only consists of that file? That was a known business model in the early 90th, things have moved on since. Valuable property is to be able to create such a file, to know the algorithms and approaches, how to use them, when to use them. _That_ is something that is a foundation for a business. Their behavior sounds a bit like the photographer who refuses to publish his pictures for fear of them being watched...

Comment: you can ask them to compile it into a exe or something and run your data on it to produce the desired output and then carry on in your own workspace. http://uk.mathworks.com/products/compiler/

Comment: Though not on topic for SO, they have 2 options. They can create a [protected function file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcode.html) or [compile the code](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/). Living vicariously through people on the internet it seems like of the two, compiling the code would be more secure than the p-code. Neither option is completely secure.

Comment: *Note:   The pcode function obfuscates your .m files, it does not encrypt them. While the content in a .p file is difficult to understand, it should not be considered secure. It is not recommended that you P-code files to protect your intellectual property.* say the [official docs](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcode.html)

Comment: You could ask them to create a mex file, that is perfectly usable in the regular MATLAB environment.

Comment: P-coding files takes less than a second and the output looks like this `v01.00v00.00 ÀŠ±  %    
y¥´TÿŠ—<ý.ŽÝ•¾k¢ AãPÛ§ ...`. I am sure there are ways to crack the obfuscation algorithm, however it can be done if that is specifically your job, cracking algorithms. However, for the use case in the question I would still recommend this option.